# Webkit button: background color overflows round corners

Tags: webkit, background-color, css

I'm trying to make a rounded button using `-webkit-border-radius`

This gives me this button (in Safari):

[image: round corner with background color]

You can see that the background color overflows in the rounding. I tried changing border size and radius, but it doesn't help. Is this a rendering bug with Safari or something?

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ento/pDTzK/) that illustrates the problem and the fix answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's addressed here on http://tumble.sneak.co.nz/post/928998513/fixing-the-background-bleed?d1dc0f00 Mike Harding's blog:

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a rendering bug with WebKit. [Adam Betts on Twitter](http://twitter.com/adambetts/status/20735454386):

> We're at Safari 5 and border-radius
>   artifacts is still here. Why isn't
>   this fixed already?
>   http://lensco.be/test/border-radius-artifacts/